# Proving the triangle inequality for a positive linear functional on function spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathscr{L},\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ be one of the spaces $(L^p(\mu), \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^p(\mu)}), 1\le p <\infty, (C_\infty(X), \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty),$ or $(C_b(X),\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ and $I:\mathscr{L} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive linear functional.

Then the proof that $I$ satisfies the triangle inequality, i.e. $|I(u)|\le I(|u|)$ for all $u\in \mathscr{L}$ is given by $\pm u \le |u|$ and using the fact that $I$ is monotone, i.e. $I(u)\le I(v)$ for all $u\le v$.

I really can't figure out why $\pm u \le |u|$ gives $|I(u)| \le I(|u|)$. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the definition of "positive". If $\pm u\leq |u|$, then $|u|\mp u\geq0$, so
$$
I(|u|\mp u)\geq0,
$$
which is
$$
\pm I(u)=I(\pm u)\leq I(|u|). 
$$
Now use that for a real number $r$, $|r|=\max\pm r$.